# Need help in creating a valid unicode to create a point marker in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm relatively new at Python, currently running Python 3.8. I want to take advantage of the many symbols in the DejaVuSans (default font for Matplotlib).

Rather than have users of my program type in the entire unicode sequence (e.g., `$\0041$` to plot the letter A) I want them only to record `0041` and I'd build the full code programmatically. It's not working, perhaps a newbie mistake.

The code included is sample code from Matplotlib Basemap, and I'm just changing the parameter to set up the marker. I have a print statement, that shows the variable (mymarker) looks like I've built it correctly, but it fails. If I replace mymarker variable and with `marker="$\0041$"` the program runs fine.

[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap(projection='ortho', 
              lat_0=0, lon_0=0)

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

lons = [0, 10, -20, -20]
lats = [0, -10, 40, -20]

x, y = map(lons, lats)

unicod_sym = "0041"

mymarker="\"$\\"+unicod_sym+"$\""

print (mymarker)

map.scatter(x, y, marker=mymarker,s=125, color = 'blue', linewidth=.5)

plt.show()
```

> ============================= RESTART: C:/Users/dbwal/Documents/Code/Python/LearningPython/basemap_scatter_testunicodes.py
> ============================= "$\0041$" Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py",
> line 2617, in parse
> result = self._expression.parseString(s)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1955,
> in parseString
> raise exc   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py",
> line 2775, in unknown_symbol
> raise ParseFatalException(s, loc, "Unknown symbol: %s" % c) pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: , found ''  (at char
> 0), (line:1, col:1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/dbwal/Documents/Code/Python/LearningPython/basemap_scatter_testunicodes.py",
> line 22, in 
> map.scatter(x, y, marker=mymarker,s=125, color = 'blue', linewidth=.5)   File
> "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_*init*_.py",
> line 564, in with_transform
> return plotfunc(self,x,y,*args,**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_*init*_.py",
> line 3262, in scatter
> ret =  ax.scatter(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py",
> line 1438, in inner
> return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py",
> line 411, in wrapper
> return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py",
> line 4473, in scatter
> marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py",
> line 228, in **init**
> self.set_marker(marker)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py",
> line 313, in set_marker
> self._recache()   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py",
> line 241, in _recache
> self._marker_function()   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py",
> line 395, in _set_mathtext_path
> text = TextPath(xy=(0, 0), s=self.get_marker(),   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py",
> line 397, in **init**
> self._vertices, self._codes = text_to_path.get_text_path(   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py",
> line 128, in get_text_path
> glyph_info, glyph_map, rects = self.get_glyphs_mathtext(prop, s)   File
> "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py",
> line 185, in get_glyphs_mathtext
> width, height, descent, glyphs, rects = self.mathtext_parser.parse(   File
> "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py",
> line 3340, in parse
> return self._parse_cached(   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py",
> line 3364, in _parse_cached
> box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)   File "C:\Users\dbwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py",
> line 2619, in parse
> raise ValueError("\n".join(["", ValueError:  \0041 ^ Unknown symbol: , found ''  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Comment: I'd like to note that [Basemap has reached EoL in 2020](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/intro.html#cartopy-new-management-and-eol-announcement).  If you are expanding an established, large Basemap project, then using Basemap in 2021 makes sense, otherwise I'd use Cartopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass the quotes in as part of the marker.  If you want to use the letter A in mathtext font, you just pass $A$.  In code, that would be

```
marker = "$A$"
```

No escapes, no quotes no backslashes.  If you really need to pass a Unicode codepoint, it is:

```
marker = "$\u266B$"
```

HOWEVER, that string contains exactly three characters: a dollar sign, a beamed eighth note, and a dollar sign.  If you REALLY need to convert a 4-digit hex value to unicode, you use `chr`:

```
marker = "$" + chr(0x266B) + "$"
```

Comment: The "A" was just a hypothetical example.  I could have users passing in lat/long files with potential 25 different symbols.  I'm trying to make their data entry easier, so they could just enter the symbol code, and I'd build the rest of the required code programmatically.  The error in the last line of the screen-dump says I have an unknown symbol (the backslash) in front of the 4 digit code, which is causing the failure.

Comment: Right, because that's incorrect.  The string that matplotlib sees will never have a backslash in it, as I described in my answer.

Comment: Using the hex code allows me to create the variable correctly.  It works.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidWalsh If an answer works for you, you could think of _accepting_ it (i.e., clicking the green check mark left of the answer). ፨ On this site, accepting an answer is the most significant expression of gratitude…